# Unsupported operand types: string + int : in Symfony form events in Collection Type

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony6

I'm getting following error:

> $data->getData() is null in Symfony form events in Collection Type

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder
        ->add('mcs', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type'=> McType::class,
            'label' => false,
            'entry_options' => ['label' => false ],
            'by_reference' => false,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
        ]);
    ;
}
```

Mctype:

```
        ->add('region', EntityType::class,[
            'label' => 'Region',
            'class' => Region::class,
            'choice_label' => function(Region $region){
                return $region->getName();
            }
        ])

    $formModifier = function(FormInterface $form, Region $region = null){
        $locations = null === $region ? [] : $region->getLocation();
        $form->add('location', EntityType::class, [
            'label' => 'Location',
            'class' => Location::class,
            'choices' => $locations
        ]);
    };       
    
    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function(FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier){
            $data = $event->getData();
            $region = null;
    
            if ($data instanceof Mc) {
                $region = $data->getRegion();
            }
            $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getRegion());
    });

    $builder->get('region')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function(FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier){
            $region = $event->getForm()->getData();
            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $region);
        }
    );
```

Region and Location are both related m-to-o relation with Mc. Did similar stuff with other class it worked, but seems not to work with collection type..

Update:

After implementing :

```
            $region = null;
    
            if ($data instanceof Mc) {
                $region = $data->getRegion();
            }
```

I'm  getting following error:

**Unsupported operand types: string + int**

Comment: For reasons I never really understood some events are fired twice.  The first with no data.  Just for kicks try adding a `if ($data === null) return;` and see if that is the case here.

Comment: @Cerad adding those line gives me this error **Neither the property "location" nor one of the methods "location()", "getlocation()"/"islocation()"/"haslocation()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView".**

Comment: Well that is progress at least.  It means your $formModifier is now being called.  Your code suggests that location is part of the Region entity? Probably need a sub form type but your code is a bit confusing.

Comment: @Cerad after a couple of try, I came with, perhaps the solution, but now it is giving me tis error. **Unsupported operand types: string + int** let me update the code.